# index.html not loading local CSS

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have lately started using AngularCLI. I had transferred all my files from Angular2 to AngularCLI project.

But It is not loading some local css file but it is loading other css files?

Current Directory is:

```
-src
--index
--styles.css
--app
---angular2-fullcalendar
----fullcalendar.min.css
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Cudyangularcli</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../src/app/angular2-fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.css" >
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

error is:
[image]

Comment: from angular-cli readme: "You can add more global styles via the apps[0].styles property in angular-cli.json." https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cli#global-styles

Comment: I think the path is wrong, when you run your app the root of your app is set as `src` folder, in  this case you should redirect to `/app/...`.

Comment: @hakany tried. still the same error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not loading, because you need to use `angular-cli.json` file to add css files into project, not the `index.html`. To do so, simply open `angular-cli-json` and add css files into `styles`:

```
"styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "another-styles.css"
]
```

Comment: Make sure to delete css links from `index.html` and check if you path to certain .css files are correct.

Comment: referring in index.html works for external css files (cdn etc.) internal files have to be mentioned in angular.json (config file)

Answer (score 8):

create directory `src/assets/css` and put your file `fullcalendar.min.css` in `src/assets/css`.

Point to it with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/fullcalendar.min.css">
```

angular-cli build command will copy the directory `assets` and its contents to `dist/assets` as stated in `.angular-cli.json`:

```
"apps": [{"assets": ["assets"] ...} ...]
```

I use following directory structure:

```
src/assets/css
src/assets/js
src/assets/icons
...
```

You can also set `"apps": [{"styles": ["angular2-fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.css"] ...} ...]` in `.angular-cli.json` as @Haseoh mentioned.

The difference is that `assets` will copy the css file as is to the `dist` directory. `styles` will bundle the contents of the css file to the file `styles.bundle.js`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically by default the path for styles.css is specified in angular-cli.json.So you don't need to call inside index.html.It will load automatically.
"styles": ["styles.css",].If you have any other css files.specify this here.And add path as href="../path".